# pg_search_scope with empty string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I am using pg_search for fulltext search, it works fine when I type a search term, but when I give it a empty string I expect it to return all models, instead I get no results.

How can I configure pg_search_scope to return all models on empty search?

Thank you

Comment: I needed this functionality also. What I did was simply used `scoped` to return all records from the Document table created by pg_search. However I'm not sure that pg_search_scope uses this table, I believe it's only used when you use `multisearchable` in your model instead (for searching multiple models simultaneously). if so, then you can get all records using: `PgSearch::Document.scoped`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my answer from https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search/issues/49

---

I don't think that having an empty query should always trigger all records, for a couple reasons.

First, I don't think that there is a well-defined order to return records in. (The usual sorting by search rank is meaningless without a query)

Second, I think that the database should define how the various search features treat a blank string, so that all of the logic lives in just one place.

So, I want to offer this workaround, which I think will work out better for your situation.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope :search_by_name, :against => :name

  def self.search(query)
    if query.present?
      search_by_name(query)
    else
      # No query? Return all records, newest first.
      order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
end
```

This solution should still be chainable, so you can call something like this in your controller safely (assuming you're using a pagination library like kaminari.

```
MyModel.where(:published => true).search(params[:query]).page(params[:page])
```